# Procedures if there was a shuttle decompression in the vacuum of space

Tags: space-shuttle, procedure, emergency, decompression

Has NASA ever published what the space shuttle astronauts would be tasked to do if a potentially catastrophic decompression occurred in space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The procedures can be found in the [Orbit Pocket Checklist](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/359853main_OPCL_G_M_10.pdf), page 4-3.  The title is O2 (N2) FLOW HIGH / CAB P LOW / dP/dT.

Since your question only asks *whether it exists / has been published*, I will not attempt to explain it.

The procedure is lengthy, here is the first page.

[image]